# Show inner elements in an element on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div with a background image and buttons on top of them. What I want is for the buttons to appear when I hover over the outer div.

Below are two simple examples. The first one has the two divs separated for hovering and showing. The second has one div inside the other. What am I missing to display the inside div on hover?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dtl-image {
  border:1px solid #000;
  min-height:300px;
  background: center / contain no-repeat url("https://inventivewebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/IWD-Logo-w-text-2016_600x425.png");
}

.img-hover {
  display: none;
}
    
.dtl-image:hover + .img-hover {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Display an Element Below Image on Hover </h2>

<div class="dtl-image"></div>
<div class="img-hover">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>

<h2>Display an Inside Element Below Image on Hover</h2>

<div class="dtl-image">
  <div class="img-hover">I am shown when someone hovers over the outer div.</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think, that it is possible to make an element visible by hovering another element, if you only use CSS. But it is easily possible with JavaScript.

Comment: Change the css from ```.dtl-image:hover + .img-hover {display: block;}``` to ```.dtl-image:hover + .img-hover, .dtl-image:hover > .img-hover {display: block;}```. Meaning add this in your css ```.dtl-image:hover > .img-hover```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use positioning for that, rather than `display: none`, as it's more accessible. Here, I've set the outer div to `position: relative` and the inner to `position: absolute;`:

```css
.dtl-image {
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid #000;
  min-height:300px;
  background: center / contain no-repeat url("https://inventivewebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/IWD-Logo-w-text-2016_600x425.png");
}

.img-hover {
  left: 10000px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.1);
  position: absolute;
}
    
.dtl-image:hover .img-hover {
  inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Display an Inside Element Above Image on Hover</h2>

<div class="dtl-image">
  <div class="img-hover">I am shown when someone hovers over the outer div.</div>
</div>
```

I assume that's the effect you wanted. If not, please clarify!

Comment: That works for me! Thanks. I realized I was attempting more CSS than I needed but thanks for the positioning comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can either simply remove the "+", which specifies that the `.img-hover` you are targeting is a sibling to the `div` being hovered, or you can specify that you would like to select the child `.img-hover` inside of the `div` being hovered with `>`. Both options should give you the result you are after.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dtl-image {
    border:1px solid #000;
    min-height:300px;
    background: center / contain no-repeat url("https://inventivewebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/IWD-Logo-w-text-2016_600x425.png");
}

.img-hover {
    display: none;
}

.dtl-image:hover .img-hover {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Display an Inside Element Below Image on Hover</h2>

<div class="dtl-image">
  <div class="img-hover">I am shown when someone hovers over the outer div.</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```